# how to log in a global zone in solaris 10

Tags: networking, admin, solaris-10, zone

I recently joined a company with little documentation, I'm having a hard time entering a global zone.
I have run the following comannds but no luck:

```
arp -a | grep SPLA
e1000g10 192.168.6.5          255.255.255.255 SPLA     00:23:8b:89:dd:6a
e1000g10 cmovel-pf01          255.255.255.255 SPLA     00:23:8b:89:dd:6a
e1000g10 fundamo.app          255.255.255.255 SPLA     00:23:8b:89:dd:6a
```

and :

```
/usr/sbin/zoneadm list -vi
ID NAME             STATUS     PATH                           BRAND    IP
 2 cmovel-pf01      running    /                              native   shared
```

and

```
zonecfg -z cmovel-pf01 info
zonecfg can only be run from the global zone.
```

How do I enter the global zone

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try ~.(tilde and then dot).

Comment: Does not work`zonename` `cmovel-pf01`  ` ~.`  `bash: ~.: command not found`

Comment: What did you exactly enter? How are you connected to this system(console/ssh)?

Comment: I´ve used  the tilde and full stop (~.), I am using ssh using putty

Comment: Unfortunately if you are logged to a local zone directly using ssh then you can not get to the global zone - it's isolated. Instead login to the global zone using ssh or console. ~. would only work if you login to a NGZ from the GZ using zlogin.